# showing the two categorical axis(X,Y) in plot for only top (n) , may be top 10 or 20 ( of X axis ) unique values

Tags: python, pandas, plot

[image: observed pic 3][image: observed picture 2][image: observed o/p]I am having some data of 13961 rows in pandas DF, I have 30+ of unique values for the category in X axis( City name ) and one more feature 'Retention Flag' in Y axis with only two levels(namely Retained/not retained).

While ploting using pd.crosstab ( it is showing all the 30+ cities-unique values in the X axis which is too clumsy and dense to understand). Instead can I show only the top 20/10 unique levels in X axis and leave the others ( or add them into  the category others ) ? Please help, not mandate to deal only with pd.crosstab.

I have created pd.cross tab, X axis-BORROWER_CITY , Y axis-'Retention_Flag'

This shows all the 30+ cities in X axis, instead i need only the top n (20/30 ) to be shown in the X axis labels

```
     df2=data.groupby("BORROWER_CITY") ['Retention_Flag'].value_counts().groupby(level=1).nlargest(4).unstack(fill_value=0)
    df2.plot(kind='bar')


The o/p obtained is shown above:

Retention_Flag                Non Retained  Retained
Retention_Flag BORROWER_CITY                        
Non Retained   Bangalore               837         0
               Delhi                  1477         0
               Mumbai                 2507         0
               Pune                    838         0
Retained       Bangalore                 0        52
               Chennai                   0       106
               Mumbai                    0       168
               Pune                      0        67

the plot is shown above with 'RetentionFlag,BORROWER_CITY'in X axis - 8 
entries

instead of having observed pic 2, having two entries for city column in 
Xaxis for ( retained/non retained ) can i have single entry alone with city 
name since, already i have legend for the flag. 

second try:
instead of nlargest, while trying with head(4) the picture is shown as 
myself expected , but it is not giving the largest value_counts() instead 
resulting the city name in alphabetical order. observed pic 3
df3=data.groupby("BORROWER_CITY")['Retention_Flag'].value_counts().groupby(level=1).head(4).unstack(fill_value=0)
print(df3)
    Retention_Flag  Non Retained  Retained
BORROWER_CITY                         
Adilabad                   2         0
Agra                      17         0
Ahmedabad                434        21
Ahmednagar                19         1
Alappuzha                  0         1
Ambala                     0         2
df3.plot(kind='bar')

the plot is shown above with 'BORROWER_CITY'in X axis - 6 entries
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can count top values per both categories with [`SeriesGroupBy.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.value_counts.html) and [`GroupBy.head`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.head.html), then reshape by [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
data = pd.DataFrame({
        'BORROWER_CITY':list('abcdabaaadab'),
         'Retention_Flag':['Ret', 'Non ret'] * 6,

})

print (data)
   BORROWER_CITY Retention_Flag
0              a            Ret
1              b        Non ret
2              c            Ret
3              d        Non ret
4              a            Ret
5              b        Non ret
6              a            Ret
7              a        Non ret
8              a            Ret
9              d        Non ret
10             a            Ret
11             b        Non ret
```

---

```
df1 = pd.crosstab(data['BORROWER_CITY'],data['Retention_Flag'])
print (df1)
Retention_Flag  Non ret  Ret
BORROWER_CITY               
a                     1    5
b                     3    0
c                     0    1
d                     2    0
```

---

```
N = 2
df2 = (data.groupby('BORROWER_CITY')['Retention_Flag']
           .value_counts()
           .groupby(level=1)
           .head(N)
           .unstack(fill_value=0))
print (df2)
Retention_Flag  Non ret  Ret
BORROWER_CITY               
a                     1    5
b                     3    0
c                     0    1
```

---

```
df2.plot(kind='bar')
```

EDIT:

Solution with `nlargest`:

```
N = 2
df3 = (data.groupby('BORROWER_CITY')['Retention_Flag']
           .value_counts()
           .groupby(level=1)
           .head(N)
           .unstack(fill_value=0))
print (df3)
```

Comment: Hi Jezreal , I have already tried this kind of code as below:  
                                                            data.groupby("BORROWER_CITY")['Retention_Flag'].value_counts().groupby(level=1).nlargest(4).plot.bar()... but retention and non-retention both falls in the X axis for all the cities in legend, I need something with the kind of stacked bar plot or to differentiate them with some colors with respect to the two levels in 'Retention_Flag'

Comment: `but retention and non-retention both falls in the X axis for all the cities in legend` - there is error? Can you explain more?

Comment: Yes, for the above mentioned code it shows , top most four cities of retention first , and top most four cities of non retention later. All are in X axis . Instead, Can I have something like stacked bar plot and having two levels for Retention Flag ( Rentained/Non retained ) with legends ...please help

Comment: @Ayyasamy - So you need `df2.plot.bar(stacked=True)` instead `df2.plot(kind='bar')` ?

Comment: @Ayyasamy - But maybe I dont understand, what need, can you explian more what is expected output from my sample data?

Comment: I tired it, in the above comment groupby(level=1).nlargest(4) , I am getting the X axis issue like both ( both retentained/non retained flags) comes around 8 times, if i use .head(4) instead of nlargest(4) i can get the plot as like i wish, but it is not the top 4 values based on value_counts(), instead, it shows the first four cities as per the alphabetical order, any suggestion to mitigate this please ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197815/discussion-between-jezrael-and-ayyasamy).

Comment: few more pictures and data have been added, check for your reference please